# Forcing Holo UI in apps on Samsung devices

Tags: android

I've an app that is themed on Holo.Light theme. AOSP ICS, Honeycomb behave just fine but on Samsung TouchWiz Honeycomb, EditText backgrounds, checkboxes, etc changes to TouchWiz. How can I force it to Holo theme?

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Holo.light">
```

Comment: maybe this will work @android:style/Holo.light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set it on a per-activity basis.

```
<activity
    android:name=".login"
    android:label="@string/login"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"/>

<activity
    android:name=".Preferences"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
```

Rather than on the overall app level.  That has worked for me.  Also, one thing to consider, Samsung may not have the same stylings in the Holo theme.  I've never owned a Touchwiz tablet, but [Holo was not required till ICS](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html).  You say the device you are using is Honeycomb.  Do other apps successfully use holo themes?  If that's the case, you could try to implement the [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) library to force a Holo Theme.

Comment: Can you confirm that Samsung Touchwiz Honeycomb devices have a holo theme to begin with?  What happens if you download a Holo app from the market.  Does it retain stock holo items?

Comment: I would try a non-google app, just to be sure.  I remember on my touchwiz phone, non-google apps didn't use the stock theme when google apps did.  Still, that's a bit of a long shot.  Can you post a little more of the manifest?  Perhaps the full XML of the activity you are trying to make HOLO?